# Is there a way to read a picture pixel by pixel in unity without any distortions

Tags: unity, c#, textures

In my unity project I have an image file which contains information. I would like to be able to read this .bmp file pixel by pixel. So I tried simply loading a sprite, and then reading its texture. However when I do that, the loaded texture appears to be different than the image I'm using, as if it was compressed. I tried modifying the asset settings (making it an advanced texture with point filter mode, and setting format to argb32bit uncompressed) but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

EDIT: Some additional information,

The code with which I load the image into a pixel array

```
// sprites from which paths will be loaded
public Sprite[] path_maps;
// Color 24 array which contains the texture bitmap
private Color32[] pixels;
// graph with paths
public Graph[] graphs;

void Start () {
    // I skipped some  code that doesn't matter to the problem

    // go through all path maps
    for (int i = 0; i < path_maps.Length; i++) {
        // load sprite into pixels array
        pixels = path_maps[i].texture.GetPixels32 ();
        // create new graph
        graphs [i] = new Graph ();
        // get graph from path map
        graphs[i].pixels_to_graph(pixels, path_maps[i].texture.width, path_maps[i].texture.height, camera_width, camera_height);
    }

}
```

The function which reads pixels and creates node for each colored pixel (only relevant part of the function)

```
public void pixels_to_graph (Color32[] pixels, int width, int height, double camera_width, double camera_height)
{
    // assign pixels width and height
    pixels_width = width;
    pixels_height = height;
    // assign camera dimensions
    this.camera_width = camera_width;
    this.camera_height = camera_height;
    // First create as many nodes as there are colored pixels (simply read the pixel map)
    // Note that pixel map contains the bitmap from bottom to the top (left bottom to top right)
    // create nodes array
    pixel_nodes = new Node[width*height];
    // current position in pixel array. Made for easier calculations
    int carriage = 0;
    // go through all rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        // go column by column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            // if it's transparent or white - ignore
            if (pixels [carriage].a == 0 || pixels [carriage].Equals (col_white))
                continue;
            // else add node to the node array
            pixel_nodes [carriage] = new Node (j, i, pixels_width, pixels_height, camera_width, camera_height); // note that i is the y position while j is the x position
            // add node to nodes list
            nodes.Add (pixel_nodes [carriage]);
            carriage++;
        }
    }
```

I detect the problem in the above `pixels_to_graph function`. When I debug it with a 1680x1050 image, that has pixels in its bottom left corner (three black squares with 1 pixel distance between them, of size 3x3px, 2x2px, 1x1px) it only detects the 3x3 one, the colour value at position of the other 2 squares is white. When I tried other shapes I also discovered other distortions, some 1px wide lines are not there, as well as single pixels.

My current texture settings (though note I tried different options but some of them don't display anything, this one at least displays something):
[image]

Comment: Do you need to *display* this image? If not (and I'm curious what it's an image of) you might consider loading the binary file directly with System.IO

Comment: @jhocking I do not, but I was hoping for unity based solution. Also isn't System.IO system dependent? (As in If I  were to use it I would have to modify the code for different OS). And this file contains possible paths for a 2d game, which are then loaded and changed into graph.

Comment: @DMGregory done, you are right I should have done it at the very beginning.

Comment: @DMGregory as you can see I attached a picture with my current texture settings (it is already set to none)

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I'd misread your settings. Very odd. I've done this kind of pixel-by-pixel traversal before without issues. I'll see if I can reproduce the problem you describe. In the meantime, have you tried displaying the texture on an appropriately-sized quad or UI image to confirm what's going on visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp. It appears to have been a codding error. In the above code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // if it's transparent or white - ignore
        if (pixels [carriage].a == 0 || pixels [carriage].Equals (col_white))
            continue; <------------ BUG LOCATION
        // else add node to the node array
        pixel_nodes [carriage] = new Node (j, i, pixels_width, pixels_height, camera_width, camera_height); // note that i is the y position while j is the x position
        // add node to nodes list
        nodes.Add (pixel_nodes [carriage]);
        carriage++;
    }
```

because of this continue the carriage position does not change when alpha is zero or when color white is found. Obviously I wasted 2 days debugging an error that was caused by trying to make code "better".

Comment: AUGH I missed it too! Good catch. In my attempts to reproduce the problem, I only managed to create the inverse: I'm counting too many marked texels somehow. O_o That'll be a curiosity for another time...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your texture format is set to `RGBA Compressed` (bottom of the texture panel), which might be why your output isn't pixel perfect. Try setting it to `RGB 24 bit`instead, which should disable compression and give you the result you're after. More details on texture formats can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) under 'Per-Platform Overrides'